# How can I validate an XHTML5 document in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, html, xml-parsing, xhtml

My PHP script tries to load a valid XHTML5 file, do some manipulations using the DOM, and output it to the client.

However, in order to use `document::getElementById()`, I have to validate the document first.

The PHP script can not do so because there is no DTD in HTML5. How can I do this?

Comment: You mean HTML5 instead of XHTML5 I guess??

Comment: @Sirko: [wiki states otherwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5#XHTML5), extended to XHTML5...

Comment: I really mean XHTML5 served as application/xhtml+xml

Comment: Interesting question. It's a problem that DOM4 works around, but DOM4 is not backward compatible and isn't much use for generic XML.

Comment: Why don't you add the DTD your own? What prevents you doing so?

Comment: What do you mean to add DTD my own? XHTML5 documents start with <!DOCTYPE html> which is not a real DTD.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found a hack which allow me to use document::getElementById() without validation:

```
// HACK
foreach ($document->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element) {
    try {
        $element->setIdAttribute('id', TRUE);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: That "hack" has been outlined in a previous question. If that really solves your issue, I suggest to close against it. E.g. (as outlined in) [How do I parse partial HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1933631/367456)

Comment: Or as outlined here: [PHP HTML DomDocument getElementById problems](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3391942/367456) or here: [how to set id of an element using PHP dom?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3617825/367456) or here: [help with DOMDocument class in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2441208/367456) - Also related: [Simplify PHP DOM XML parsing - how?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3405117/367456)